# Руководствоваться или руководиться?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Когда правильно говорить «руководствоваться», а когда — «руководиться»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря русского языка под редакцией С.И. Ожегова (год издания найти не могу, но по виду книга очень старая):
**РУКОВОДИ́ТЬСЯ**; несовер., чем. Направлять свою деятельность сообразно с чему-нибудь. *Руководиться велением долга*.
**РУКОВОДСТВОВАТЬСЯ**; несов. То же, что руководиться. *Руководствоваться правилами*.

На Грамоте.ру есть только "руководствоваться".

Оба слова зафиксированы в словарях, так что употребление их не будет ошибочным. Хотя я, если честно, не встречала ни в художественной литературе, ни научных статьях, ни просто в статьях "руководиться чем-либо". Полагаю (только лишь полагаю), что этот вариант вышел (или выходит) из употребления.

Answer (score 0):

Тезаурус русской деловой лексики:
**руководиться**
**Syn**: см. руководствоваться

Словарь русских синонимов:
**руководиться**
гл. несов.
• руководствоваться
• следовать

[**Толковый словарь Ушакова**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1012470/%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%AF):
РУКОВОДИ́ТЬСЯ, руковожусь, руководишься и (устар.) руководишься; руководящийся, несовер. (книжн.).

1. *чем*. Направлять свою деятельность сообразно чему-нибудь, в зависимости от чего-нибудь, поступать согласно с чем-нибудь.
2. *кем-чем*. страд. к руководить (редк.).
   Учреждение руководится опытным работником.

*Но скоро, **руководясь** инстинктом, аллигатор нырнул в одну из глубоких ям и исчез.*
Т. Рид. Оцеола, вождь семинолов

*Наказ, как того и хотела Екатерина, есть только изложение принципов, какими должен **руководиться** государственный человек, пишущий законы.*
С. Ф. Платонов. Полный курс лекций по русской истории

*Мужчина, который при женитьбе **руководится** деньгами, а не своею склонностью, живет больше в индивиде, чем в роде, а это прямо противоречит истинной сущности мира, является чем-то противоестественным и возбуждает известное презрение.*
А. Шопенгауэр. Мир как воля...

Вы не привели контекста, поэтому приходится додумывать. В **первом** значении глаголы синонимичны, их употребление практически равнозначно.

Answer (score 0):

У слова *руководиться* есть значения, не совпадающее со значением слова *руководствоваться*:

- быть руководимым кем-то:

*Эти два Йемена* **руководились** *двоюродными братьями, северный брат был социалистом, южный ― коммунистом. [С. П. Капица. Мои воспоминания (2008)]*

- возвратное от *руководить*:

*Агентивные состояния этой диатезы не имеют — даже если глагол непереходный: (15)* *мне сегодня не* **руководится**, *не царствуется. [Е. В. Падучева. О параметрах лексического значения глагола: таксономическая категория и тематический класс (2004)]*

В остальном, по-моему, это синонимы. Предположение о том, что слово *руководиться* вышло из употребления, не подтверждается поиском в Нацкорпусе:

*2. ― Русское искусство ― призвано блюсти и развивать тот дух любовной созерцательности и предметной свободы, которым оно* **руководилось** *доселе. [О русской идее (2002) // «Жизнь национальностей», 2002.10.14]*

*В своих действиях он* **руководился** *почти неосознанными стремлениями и неясной надеждой, что именно генетика поможет ему вспомнить нечто очень важное, давно забытое, но по праву ему принадлежащее. [Наль Подольский. Книга Легиона // «Октябрь», 2001]*

Дополнение.

По-моему, есть случай, когда "руководиться" поставить нельзя, а именно когда 
руководствуются каким-либо "руководством" (инструкцией, законом и т.п.). А руководиться можно только тем, что руководит тобой (чувствами, убеждениями и т. п.). Впрочем, подтверждения этому своему мнению я в словарях не нашел.